Check if entry has been cited before a certain point, or nocited
I am trying to get the related field work for my purposes. The following prints the extendedversionof-relation by a citation if this work occurs in the bibliography:
\makeatletter
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\NewBibliographyString{extendedversionof}
\renewcommand\relatedpunct{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    extendedversionof={extended version of}
}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\newbibmacro*{related:extendedversionof}[1]{%
    \entrydata*{#1}{%
        \usefield\ifentryinbib{clonesourcekey}{%
            \space
            \usefield\cite{clonesourcekey}%
        }{%
            \intitlepunct\space
            \renewcommand\@tempa[1]{\usebibmacro{related:default}{#1}}%
            \usefield\@tempa{key}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
    Test
    \nocite{Extended}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}

will print the Extended version of... inline, while \nocite{*} will cause [2] contain a citation of [1]. Here's the caveat: If I replace \nocite{*} by \cite{Extended} again, nothing will change: sure; Proceedings is being cited (namely, by Extended) and thus is in the bibliography, and thus is cited, and thus stays there... The problem is clear, I guess. So, how to I test if an entry has been (no)cited before the bibliography?
